# VMWare turn on server on-demand, APIs?

Tags: vmware, esxi

I have a environment where I have a huge pool of machines (60 thus far en growing each day), now these machines are used in a testing environment and machines do not need to be online around the clock as were paying for CPU time so I want to create a system where our users can turn on machines without having to logon through either vSphere desktop client or the vSphere site. Now i know there are systems such as plesk and similar but these are way over the top of what we need for an internal system.

Are there any API for VMWare that lets me remotely turn on virtual machines on demand?

**We are running ESXi 5.1.0 on our hosts.**

Comment: Have a look at vCenter Orchestrator, The remote management VM, and the whole APIs, google will help you around this

Comment: Thanks! I will look it up.

Comment: Maybe a [starting point](https://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/sdk_pubs.html)